# AWS Autoscaling CodeDeploy Default Hooks terminate instance on both CONTINUE and ABANDON on failure. How can I avoid that?

Tags: amazon-web-services, iis, deployment

Here is the example hook which is attached to ASG by default on registering on codedeploy. I don't my instance to terminate if the codedeploy pipeline fails for a new instance. Is there any way to achieve this?
I use IIS Windows ec2 server for my applications.

```
Name: CodeDeploy-managed-automatic-launch-deployment-hook-xcv 
Lifecycle Transition: autoscaling:EC2_INSTANCE_LAUNCHING
Default Result: ABANDON
Heartbeat timeout: 600 seconds
Notification Target ARN: arn:aws:sqs:<REGION>:<AWS_ACCOUNT_ID>:razorbill-<REGION>-prod-default-autoscaling-lifecycle-hook
```

I tried to use CONTINUE but it also terminates the instance on failure of pipeline or if I manually stop the deployment on codedeploy.